# Google Maps directionsRenderer displaying waypoints

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm new to the Google Maps v3 API and was wondering if there's a way to display waypoints with different markers when you're building directions, for example:

```
function calcRoute() {

    var request = {
        origin: "Sydney, NSW",
        destination: "Sydney, NSW",
        waypoints:[{location: "Bourke, NSW"}, {location: "Broken Hill, NSW"}],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}
```

So to phrase my question in another way, is there a way to make the waypoints appear as white dots and the origin/destination as Google's green markers?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no implemented option to use different markers for waypoints.

You must set the `suppressMarkers`-option of the directionsRenderer to false(no markers will be rendered) , parse the directionsResult and create the desired markers on your own.